# Visible sensor ray in Citadel

Tags: gazebo-citadel, ignition-citadel

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How do you get the green cone like this picture:

[image: image description]

I can't find it in my Citadel. Is it a feature for Fortess only?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27446/visible-sensor-ray-in-citadel/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can see on the release features that light visualization was added on Edifice:

https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/all/release-features#edifice

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2021-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2021-10-12**:
Ah, gotcha! So are you saying that those features are not available on Citadel at all? :(

I'm hoping to use version with a good LTS.

Edfirce will ends in 2022 while Citadel will ends in 2024.